# Replace numbers in a string with asterisks, and reveal them again

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I have a problem with the following task. I want to achieve this output for *n* = 5:

```
* 2 3 4 5
* * 3 4 5
* * * 4 5
* * * * 5
* * * * *
* * * * *
* * * * 5
* * * 4 5
* * 3 4 5
* 2 3 4 5
```

I'm stuck in the second part of the exercise. My code for now:

```js
var n = 5;
var numbers = '';

for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    numbers += i;
}

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    numbers = numbers.replace(numbers[i], '*');
    console.log(numbers);
}
```

So far I have this result:

```
*2345
**345
***45
****5
*****
```

So now I need to add the spaces between numbers/stars, and make a reverse loop. I have no idea how to do it.

In addition, there is probably a faster solution to this task than I did.

Comment: I doubt you want to use a string like you have currently. You should be able to output the correct character based on conditional logic.

Comment: Your best bet is to work out the logic for this yourself, you will learn a lot more than just using an answer. Start by looking at each line and what conditions based on the loops indexes determines what each character is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save each of the numbers you generate on a stack (an array), and then pop them from the stack in reverse order:

```js
var n = 5;
var numbers = '';
var stack = []; // <--- add this

for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    numbers += i + ' '; // add a space here
}

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    numbers = numbers.replace(i, '*'); // find/replace the digit
    console.log(numbers);
    stack.push(numbers); // <--- push on stack
}
    
while (stack.length > 0) {
    numbers = stack.pop(); // <--- pull in reverse order
    console.log(numbers); // <--- and print
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A similar way, without the use of a stack, delays the output, and gathers all the strings in two longer strings which each will have multiple lines of output:

```js
var n = 5;
var numbers = '';
var stack = [];
var output1 = ''; // <-- add this
var output2 = ''; //

for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    numbers += i + ' ';
}
numbers += '\n'; // <-- add a newline character

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    numbers = numbers.replace(i, '*');
    output1 += numbers;
    output2 = numbers + output2; //  <-- add reversed
}

console.log(output1 + output2); // <-- output both
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I might approach the problem is by having a variable that keeps track of up to which number needs to be an asterisk, doing the first half, then using a whole new for loop to do the second half.

For instance,

```
String result = '';
String line = '';
int counter = 1;

for (int line = 1; line =< 5; line++) {
  for (int i = 1; i =< 5; i++) { // note that we start at 1, since the numbers do
    if (i <= counter) {
      line += '*'; // use asterisk for positions less than or equal to counter
    else {
      line += i; // otherwise use the number itself
    }
    line += ' '; // a space always needs to be added
  }
  result += line + '\n'; // add the newline character after each line
  counter++; // move the counter over after each line
}
```

Then you can do the same loop, but make the counter go backwards. To do that, set `counter` to 5 before you begin the loop (since Strings are zero-indexed) and do `counter--` after each line.

Alternatively if you don't want to write two loops, you can increase the outer for loop's limit to 10 and have an `if` statement check if you should be subtracting from counter instead of adding, based on the value of `line`

Comment: javascript with types ... oh no.

Comment: @NinaScholz it's Java :P

Comment: Writing two loops for this is a little redundant.

Comment: @NinaScholz I notice now the question was probably written in JavaScript... I've been working in Java all day and I was taught programming in Java with these kinds of problems which probably explains why I assumed it was Java

Comment: @Confuzing that's true in terms of file size but it would provide better readability in my opinion, and its also less error prone since it's easier to think of the problem in two parts

Comment: It may be a little easier to write, but increases complexity for maintainability and scalability.

Answer (score 2):

Sticking with something similar to your approach:

```
var n = 5;
var numbers = '';

for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    numbers += i + ' ';
}

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    numbers = numbers.substr (0, i * 2) + '*' + numbers.substr (i * 2 + 1);
    console.log(numbers);
};

for (var i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    console.log(numbers);
    numbers = numbers.substr (0, i * 2) + (i + 1) + numbers.substr (i * 2 + 1);
};
```

The disadvantage of this approach is that it only works for 0-9 because the string positions break when the numbers aren't single digits.

Answer (score 1):

Decided to use this as an excuse to get more practice with immutable mapping and reducing. I used an array to hold all the rows, and reduce them at the end to a string. Each row starts as an array holding 1 to n, and each column number is then mapped to an asterisk based on the case:

```
if rowIndex <= number:
    rowIndex.
else:
    rowIndex - (2 * (rowIndex - number) - 1)
```

Essentially, [n + 1, n * 2] maps to (1, 3, 5, ..., n - 3, n - 1), which subtracted from the original range becomes [n, 1]. For the row, check if the currently selected column is less than or equal to its row's translated index, and return an asterisk or the number.

```js
// expansion number (n by 2n)
const maxNum = 5;

// make an array to size to hold all the rows
const result = Array(maxNum * 2)
    // Fill each row with an array of maxNum elements
    .fill(Array(maxNum).fill())

    // iterate over each row
    .map((row, rowIndex) =>
        // iterate over each column
        row.map((v, column) => (

            // check if the column is less than the translated rowIndex number (as mentioned above)
            column < ((rowIndex <= maxNum) ?
                rowIndex + 1 :
                2 * maxNum - rowIndex
            // if it is, replace it with an asterisk
            )) ? "*" : column + 1)

        // combine the row into a string with each column separated by a space
        .reduce((rowAsString, col) => rowAsString + " " + col)
    // combine all rows so they're on new lines
    ).reduce((rowAccum, row) => rowAccum + "\n" + row);
    
console.log(result);
```